# SdFat Arduino SD card writing

Tags: arduino, sd-card

I have hit a problem that I see no reason for it to be there.

The basic idea is to write to an SD card using the SdFat library in Arduino to log data.

Between logging the device will go to sleep and using a MOSFET I will switch off the SD card completely to save power.

The whole code works but only when I read the data from the file that I just wrote to.
When I take out the code to read from the file it creates the file but does not write to it at all.

For now I am using a delay instead of making the micro sleep just to reduce the things to focus on.

Here is the code that works with the reading the file, using the example file just to get this thing working for now.

```
const int chipSelect = 4;
/*
 The circuit:
 * SD card attached to SPI bus as follows:
 ** MOSI - pin 11
 ** MISO - pin 12
 ** CLK - pin 13
 ** CS - pin 4   
 */
#include <SdFat.h>
SdFat sd;
SdFile myFile;

char fileName[] = "2468.txt";
int sdPower = 3;
void setup() 
{  
  pinMode(sdPower,OUTPUT);
}

void loop() 
{  
  digitalWrite(sdPower,HIGH);
  sd.begin(chipSelect, SPI_HALF_SPEED);
  myFile.open(fileName, O_RDWR | O_CREAT | O_AT_END);

  myFile.println("Hello World");


  myFile.close();  

  // re-open the file for reading:
  if (!myFile.open(fileName, O_READ)) {
    sd.errorHalt("opening test.txt for read failed");
  }

  // read from the file until there's nothing else in it:
  int data;
  while ((data = myFile.read()) >= 0) Serial.write(data);
  // close the file:
  myFile.close();

  digitalWrite(sdPower,LOW);
 delay(1000);  
}
```

The above works but the moment I take the last few lines out that do the reading it does not write to the file, like this.

```
const int chipSelect = 4;
/*
 The circuit:
 * SD card attached to SPI bus as follows:
 ** MOSI - pin 11
 ** MISO - pin 12
 ** CLK - pin 13
 ** CS - pin 4   
 */
#include <SdFat.h>
SdFat sd;
SdFile myFile;

char fileName[] = "2468.txt";
int sdPower = 3;
void setup() 
{  
  pinMode(sdPower,OUTPUT);
}

void loop() 
{  
  digitalWrite(3,HIGH);
  sd.begin(chipSelect, SPI_HALF_SPEED);
  myFile.open(fileName, O_RDWR | O_CREAT | O_AT_END);

  myFile.println("Hello World");


  myFile.close();  

  digitalWrite(3,LOW);
 delay(1000);  
}
```

Yet it still creates the file.
This is really confusing me.

Why does the program not write when it has the read section removed? surly because I am closing the file in both instances it should not matter ?

Comment: I too am stumped at this.  Did you ever work out what was wrong?

Answer (score 2):

I know this is old but I was on the same situation, so I will write my answer to help anyone else who seeks for this.

The solution is simple, you must `flush()` the content before closing the file:

```
myFile.println("Hello World");
myFile.flush();
myFile.close();
```

This will ensure the content is written to the SD card.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the power to the card is being removed

```
 {
 digitalWrite(3,LOW);
 }
```

before the directory and FAT data had been written do the card by the `close()` command. Try a 1 second delay  delay before turning the card off. The reading data loop in the working example assures the file has been closed properly ;-)